# Windows Deployment Services PXE Boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows, 16.04, nfs, pxe

Currently, I am using Windows Deployment Services for deployments of operating systems to devices within my home and recently I had a troublesome device that I was attempting to PXE Boot to determine whether it was a driver issue or a hardware issue. I have booted multiple Linux OS' with Windows Deployment Service via ISOLINIX/PXELINUX package but the latest release of Ubuntu fails.

This is the entry within default of pxeboot.cfg:

```
LABEL Ubuntu
menu label ^Ubuntu 16-04 LTS
# Load the correct kernel
kernel /Images/Ubuntu-16.04/casper/vmlinuz.efi
# Boot options
append boot=casper netboot=nfs root=/Images/ScratchDir nfsroot=10.0.XXX.XXX:/WDServices/Boot/x64/Images/Ubuntu-16.04 priority=low vga=normal initrd=/Images/Ubuntu-16.04/casper/initrd.lz ip=dhcp
```

However, the boot fails with the following errors:

**"Mounting dev on /dev/root failed: no such file or directory" and "Mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: no such file or directory."**

This is using the Ubuntu 16.04 ISO as it contains the "Live CD" option which is all that's needed for this scenario as an installation into that system is not something that can be done.

The NFS Shares have been set to read/write to verify whether it was a permission issue on the Windows 2012 Server but it did not work.